# Specifically lower case email-addresses only

Tags: regular-expression, cygwin

Example (random) text:

```
StackOverflow@icloud.com:Portuguesa-Span103
StackOverflow@gmail.com-Snip1031
Stackoverflow@icloud.com:Sanchismo103
```

Desired output:

```
stackoverflow@icloud.com:Portuguesa-Span103
stackoverflow@gmail.com-Snip1031
stackoverflow@icloud.com:Sanchismo103
```

Generally this is the email-address Regex I tend to use,

```
[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}
```

I would like for the command to find all email-addresses and simply lowercase them regardless of the format on each line. Whilst still maintaining the normal capitalisation on the rest of the line (nothing else besides email-addresses are changed).

My preferred tool of use is bash (and related tools), I currently have not tried doing this myself, as I don't know where to start.

I am using Gnu/Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks "ctrl-alt-delor", my terminology is terrible lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using GNU sed, you can use:

```
sed -e 's/^\([^@]*\)@/\L\1@/' file
```

This converts everything from the beginning of the line up to the first `@` to lowercase.  e.g.

```
$ sed -e 's/^\([^@]*\)@/\L\1@/' input.txt
stackoverflow@icloud.com:Portuguesa-Span103
stackoverflow@gmail.com-Snip1031
stackoverflow@icloud.com:Sanchismo103
```

If the email addresses are not at the beginning of each line, and/or if there may be multiple email addresses on a line, you would use `\b` instead of `^` to anchor the search-and-replace to the word-boundary marker instead of the start of line:

```
sed -e 's/\b\([^@]*\)@/\L\1@/g' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the regex you use is always correct, you can use it with Perl:

```
% perl -pe 's/[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}/\L$&/' foo
stackoverflow@icloud.com:Portuguesa-Span103
stackoverflow@gmail.com-Snip1031
stackoverflow@icloud.com:Sanchismo103
```

`$&` is the matched text, and `\L` makes everything after it lowercase (until a `\E`, but it's not needed here).